# Парсинг src картинки C#

Tags: c#, htmlagilitypack

Столкнулся с проблемой парсинга в C#, не могу спарсить src ссылку на картинку, выводит какой-то непонятный путь. Помогите, пожалуйста, буду благодарен, вот код:

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;

string links = "https://www.061.ua/news/3316355/v-zaporozskom-oblastnom-sovete-podumyvaut-provesti-reorganizaciu-kommunalnoj-gostinicy-ukraina";

HtmlWeb news = new();
HtmlDocument img = news.Load(links);
string poster = img.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='article-details__poster-container']/img").GetAttributeValue("src", " ");

Console.WriteLine(poster);
```

Comment: На какую картинку, надо догадаться? `Console.WriteLine(img.DocumentNode.InnerHtml)` что выводит? Есть ли там нужная вам HTML нода?

Comment: @aepot там одна картинка. Нода есть нужная, проверил только что ,но путь выводит неверный, которого вообще нет в блоке img

Comment: поробуйте поменять `.GetAttributeValue("src", " ")` на `.Attributes["src"].Value`

Comment: Возможно запрос неверно составлен, попробуйте `SelectNodes` с этим же запросом и выведите всю коллекцию через `foreach`.

Comment: Скопируйте адрес картинки, далее нажмите F12 -> Вкладка Сеть -> обновите страницу. Как прогрузятся все запросы, нажмите там же во вкладке сеть Ctrl+F и вставьте ссылку на картинку, вам подсветит запрос и место, где эта картинка находится. Такими манипуляциями вы поймете, что в том месте, где вы ищите, в исходных данных попросту нету каких либо данных, а есть они в JSON, который в самом низу HTML.